# How to count and group not null elements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where each row represents a user and each column represents a service that the customer may have hired. I need to count how many customers hired 1 service, how many hired 2 and so on. It doesn't matter what service you hire. And there is no identifier column.

In Python I was able to do this with

```
result = services.count(axis = 1).value_counts()
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['n_clients'])
```

where 'result' is the csv with the database.

The result, in this case, are like:

|  | n_client |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 928459 |
| 2 | 280235 |
| 3 | 53731 |
| 4 | 16042 |

---

Edit: an example of the database to clarify:

| product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True |  |  |  |
| True | True |  | True |
|  |  | True |  |
|  | True |  | True |
| True |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | True |
| True | True |  |  |

In this case, the result should look like:

|  | n_client |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |

Comment: Can you post your data? A table with sample data?

Comment: Sample data to accompany your desired results please!

Comment: What does the first data set have to do with the question? Seems like, however, what you need to do if fix your design; having multiple `product` columns breaks basic normalisation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to just calculate how many products per row, then group by that number

```sql
SELECT
  v.CountProducts
  n_client = COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
      CASE WHEN product1 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN product2 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN product3 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN product4 = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) ) v(CountProducts)
GROUP BY
  CountProducts;
```

Comment: This code ends up counting how many users have each product, which is not what I need. I need to know how many customers have 1 product (regardless of what it is), how many have 2, how many have 3 and so on.

Comment: OK given you a new solution